Can I export the trained model or Docker from Google Document AI Custom Extractor?
I've trained a custom form model using Google Document AI Custom Extractor. According to the official Document AI documentation and the Google Cloud platform interface, it seems that the only way to use this model is through the API.
Is it possible to download the trained custom form model or Docker?
Thank you.
